# Uploading bulk generated data to SQL Server - how to determine batch size?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm writing a C# tool that generates data according to rules specified by the user, and need to insert all of it into a (new) table in the database.  This data could easily end up being too large to keep in memory (or even on the client's disk) at the same time.  The general flow is:

1. Generate data row
2. Insert into DataTable
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until batch size (??) is met
4. Upload batch via SqlBulkCopy, clear DataTable
5. Repeat 1-4 until total row count (potentially very large) is met.

A few notes:

- Because of the complexity of the logic, it can't really be recreated via TSQL and executed server-side.
- Generating a smaller DataTable and uploading that multiple times to meet rowcount isn't an option for this scenario.  Each cell needs to be individually set in C#.

Given that the user can potentially choose any combination of datatypes and any arbitrarily large row count, what's my best bet for determining batch size dynamically?

Comment: May not be a viable option, but it sounds like simply counting data bytes after each insert should work.

Comment: Where is data generation process happening? In the Azure cloud or "client-side"? If client-side than I assume major limiting factor will be network bandwidth and batch sizes will have negligible impact. How CPU intensive is data generation process?

Comment: Is there a requirement to actually keep multiple rows in memory as part of processing, or is the process logically generating the rows one by one? You can use an `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` to feed `SqlBulkCopy`. This at least removes any constraints on the client machine's memory. `DataTable` is a memory hog. Then the only remaining question is how large the `.BatchSize` should be, but that parameter determines the commit size at the *server* end, and is typically far less critical -- with a table lock, `0` (commit everything at once) is usually fine, even for very large inserts.

Comment: Note that even in the case where all data must be accessible at the client end for calculation purposes, using something that's *not* `DataTable` but convertible to `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` is still more memory efficient, unless the data truly is completely dynamically typed (in that case, `DataTable` is not much less efficient than any solution you'd create yourself).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @JeroenMostert!  I ended up going with your solution - implementing my own [DbDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_WriteToServer_System_Data_Common_DbDataReader_) to yield values as they're requested, since there's no immediate need to keep them in the client's memory.  If you post as an response rather than comment, I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My take for this problem is to have a similar environment to the PRODUCTION environment and do a couple of test with different values of the batch size. From those with similar performance select the one with less resource utilization.

The dynamic solution is not a good idea because you need to factor in the latency of the network and the available memory at least and is a very challenging problem on its own.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Make the batch size configurable at runtime to enable quick adjustments based on performance or errors. You can start with 10,000 rows per batch and then use 
below queries to monitor successful/terminated/throttled connections over the last x minutes and take a decision to reduce the batch size.

```
select *
from sys.database_connection_stats_ex
where start_time >= CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() AS float)) AS DATETIME)
order by start_time desc

select * 
from sys.event_log 
where event_type <> 'connection_successful' and
start_time >= CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() AS float)) AS DATETIME)
order by start_time desc
```

You should also monitor if the database was reaching the DTU limit.

```
SELECT     
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent',
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent',
(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
```

The last query can be also modified to increase the batch size if resources are below and specific threshold.